# Пакет был восстановлен .Net Framework, а не .Net Core

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

> Пакет "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3" был восстановлен с помощью
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", а не целевой платформы проекта
>   ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью
>   совместим с вашим проектом.

Ругается на следующие пакеты:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0

Это значит, что я не смогу запустить этот проект на Linux? 
Как исправить/подключить правильные аналоги, которые будут правильно работать под .Net Core?

Проект пишется в Visual Studio 2017 Community (Веб приложение - Пустой шаблон). 
Целевая платформа: .Net Core 2.0

Comment: Если бы проект был действительно Asp.Net Core, а не как у вас устаревший Asp.Net, то тогда никаких проблем не было бы. В Asp.Net Core используются Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. Везде фигурирует Microsoft.AspNetCore.* Да. там и структура проекта весьма отличается от старой.

Comment: @Bulson заменил в nuGet `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` и `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` на `Core` аналоги, как вы сказали и предупреждения исчезли. Этого достаточно для корректной работы в Linux или я ещё что-то упускаю?

Comment: Что заменил? Там вообще все другое. Надо начинать проект так [посмотрите](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/1.2.php) внимательно на картинки.

Comment: @Bulson а на счёт структуры проекта, я ориентируюсь на `Pro ASP.Net Core MVC` - 6 издание учебника Фримена. Там правда версия 1.1 рассматривается, но возможности почитать новое издание с 2.0 у меня нет)

Comment: Ну и как же вы ориентировались на Фримана ежели изначально писали проект под устаревшую версию фреймворка?

Comment: @Bulson я выбирал вот этот шаблон: http://pastexen.com/i/VZjp3crMr9.png

Comment: @Bulson кстати, никаких противоречий пока не заметил с тем, что делаю я и указано в мануале по вашей ссылке =/

Comment: А откуда тогда взялись ссылки на пакеты предыдущей версии? •Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3 - меня особо забавляет. Откуда он мог взяться?

Comment: @Bulson я ориентировался на книгу Фримена, где он описывает действия для версии Net Core 1.1, полагая, что кардинальных отличий в создании простого проекта не будет, а если будут, то смогу решить конфликты описания учебника с реальными с помощью интернета =/

Comment: @Bulson сейчас глянул ещё раз в учебник и выяснилось, что виновата моя невнимательность.. в учебнике было указано добавить как-раз Core-версии библиотек, но я при поиске в nuGet добавил обычные =/

Comment: @Bulson я просто сам через nuGet добавил выделенные в книге пакеты и допустил ошибку при переписывании названия пакета)
http://pastexen.com/i/YTic2xlkZw.png

Comment: @Bulson А `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` я не добавлял, возможно он полез зависимостью с одной из этих библиотек. Потому как после удаления обычных и установки core-версии, пропали все варнинги =/

Comment: Если не хотите плестись в хвосте прогресса, то привыкайте пользоваться англоязычными источниками знаний. Книга Фримана давно уже вышла в новой редакции по Asp.Net Core 2.0. Ее можно легко найти на торрентах, но если вы будете ждать русский перевод, то он появится аккурат к выходу Asp.Net Core 3.0. Понимаю, тяжело, но надо читать англоязычные источники.